# How can i get sample .settings file?

Tags: mule, settings, esb

I need a .settings file, is there any common repository to access dependent jars ?

i need to access dependents for Mule projects,

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Which .settings file are you referring to ?   You mean settings.xml from maven to get access to MuleSoft repository and retrieve necessary dependencies ?

If this is the case...  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb

In that link you can find all the info you need to download Mule dependencies in your project.

Example:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

NOTE: for EE ( enterprise edition) dependencies you will need usename and password that must be provided by MuleSoft team, if you are not aware of your username and password, get in touch with your company or contact with Mulesoft

Answer (score 0):

These are the common repositories which you need to include in your project

```
<repository>
       <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
       <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
       <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
       <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>



<repository>
       <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
       <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
       <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
       <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>
```